# How to know which element belongs to which session in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Lets say I have group or items

In `session('goods')` I have

```
[
 "Item1"
"Item2"
"Item3"
"Item4"
"Item5"]
```

And then I have `session('bads')` and in it

```
["Item6"
"Item7"
"Item8"
"Item9"
"Item10"]
```

I just know that there is an `Item10` and `Item4`

How do I know that these two items belong to which session?

---

Comment: You could iterate both sessions and match the value you are finding then echo or save it to a variable if it finds a match.

Comment: Highlander: _There can be only one_

Comment: @CamiloGo Don't want to hardcode the session names. There is a reason behind it! Logic is different!

Comment: what exactly does `session('goods');` return? An arrray, A collection? How are you adding items? And what are items - strings, some other scaler, or more complex objects?

Comment: you should add some informations in your question. Have you tried anythings ? Maybe add some code in order to help us help you. You should also consider reading the [How to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to create a well construct and answerable question.

Comment: Yess `session('goods') and 'bads'` are arrays. You can see the question now. If I `return session('goods')` then that output is received

Answer (score 0):

With the data structure you have, the best you can do is check both arrays with `in_array`:

```
protected function isGoodOrbad($item)
{
    if(in_array($item, session('goods')) return 'good';
    if(in_array($item, session('bads')) return 'bad';
    //neither, handle how you want
    throw new SomeException($item . ' not found');
}
```

Comment: That is the thing! I have numerous session arrays! Good and Bad was just for example

Comment: @Alen Thats why its important to give an accurate account of your problem in your question - i and others can only answer based on the details you provide. Edit you question with more details and i will endeavor to provide a better solution, probably based on a hashtable (associative array in php parlance)